# c# SerialPort can't receive binary data

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have a class reading the serial port and works ok when I send text but when changed to binary data, bytes like 0x02, 0x04... can't receive nothing, BytesToRead is zero and the DataReceived callback is not called... I tried to change the encoding and this is my configuration:

```
SerialPort _serialPortTenma = new SerialPort();
_serialPortTenma.PortName = textBox17.Text;
_serialPortTenma.BaudRate = 2400;
_serialPortTenma.Parity = Parity.None;
_serialPortTenma.DataBits = 8;
_serialPortTenma.Handshake = Handshake.None;
_serialPortTenma.StopBits = StopBits.One;
_serialPortTenma.ReadTimeout = 5000;
_serialPortTenma.WriteTimeout = 5000;
_serialPortTenma.DiscardNull = false;
_serialPortTenma.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII;
_serialPortTenma.Open();
_serialPortTenma.DiscardInBuffer();
_serialPortTenma.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataReceivedHandler2);
```

Any help???

Thanks

Comment: The documentation says: `The DataReceived event is not guaranteed to be raised for every byte received.`. Also, how are you attempting to read the bytes, and have you tried changing the Encoding to 8859-1? (`Encoding.GetEncoding(28591)`).

Comment: Could you add the code where you write binary data to the port?

Comment: You should attach the `DataReceived` event handler before you call `Open()` otherwise you might miss the event. You could also try setting `ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;`.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to change the encoding and the problem persist.

About the event handler I tested it after the open and works ok but also tried to put it before and the problem is the same and tried the ReceivedBytesThreshold = 1;

The problem only occurs the you send characters like 0x02, 0x04 that are not recognized like valid text characters because this is binary data. The binary data is send by a multimeter and I can read it ok with other programs.

Thanks

Comment: That's because those values are special characters in the ASCII Table.  The font you are using in C# probably doesn't support them as character strings.  You can prove this by printing out all the HEX values instead of the string values.  Or try sending over 0x21 or something that does have a string value for the font you're using.

Comment: Of course those values are not standard text characters and I'm not trying to get is as text, those values are binay data but can't acces to it because the SerialPort class don't receive nothing, ReceivedBytes are always zero and the DataReceived  event is not called and of course the communication is ok because I'm testing it with other program

Comment: It should receive those bytes fine.  Can you show us your code in your `DataReceived` event?

Comment: Problem is solved, the DTR should be high to give power to the multimeter interface and the manufacturer forgot to specify this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, the DTR should be high to give power to the multimeter interface and the manufacturer forgot to specify this.

Thanks